# Anchor tags not working as expected in Mozilla Firefox and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, anchor

I have a following html code:

```
<div class="share-wrap">
       <p>
        Terms and Conditions
    </p>
    <br/>
        <a href="https://sitename/en/privacy-
        statement.html#cookies" target="_blank">Cookie Policy</a>'
 </div>
```

The link works perfectly on Chrome. When i click on it it goes to another page and on the required '#cookies' id. But in Firefox and IE it goes to some other section. 
Other page has code like this:

```
<a name="cookies"></a>
 <h2 class="jump" id="cookies">Cookies</h2>
  content
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: `<a name="cookies"></a>` is pointless. The `id` on the following object has served the same purpose for about a decade.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<li>` cannot be a child element of `<div>`

Comment: <li> was by mistake..have edited it

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by the area you are linking to moving down the document as more content is loaded.

For example, if an image with intrinsic dimensions — where the size taken up by the image has to be calculated after the image file has downloaded rather than being taken from CSS or height/width attributes — appears above the content you are linking to.

Ensure that all content that isn't embedded in the HTML document has explicit sizes.